# Xcode crash when copy and paste the ViewContoller

Tags: ios, xcode

It only happens in the Xcode version 11 and the beta version of it.

When I tried to copy a view controller and paste it, it just crashed.

Any idea I can copy my view controller?

[image: version]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have solved this in the stable version which is **version 11.1 (11A1027)**.

So grab it if you are still facing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue with Xcode 11 while copy and pasting view elements on interface builder.

As an alternative, you can duplicate the desired views (CMD+D) and then move to the proper placement.